# USB Drive showing in lsusb & dmesg but not in lsblk or fdisk

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb-drive, usb-device, lsusb

I have this USB Drive that i'm trying to fix,.
When I plug it, dmesg shows the following :

```
[83630.997986] usb 1-10: new high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[83631.146553] usb 1-10: New USB device found, idVendor=ffff, idProduct=1201, bcdDevice= 0.00
[83631.146557] usb 1-10: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[83631.147917] usb-storage 1-10:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[83631.148272] scsi host4: usb-storage 1-10:1.0
[83632.166402] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     NAND     USB2DISK         0.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[83632.166579] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[83632.210532] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

and a sudo lsusb give that (Bus 001 Device 012 is the USB Drive) :

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0b0e:0312 GN Netcom Jabra EVOLVE 30 II
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 04f2:0112 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd KU-8933 Keyboard with PS/2 Mouse port
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 413c:4503 Dell Computer Corp. Dell Universal Receiver
Bus 001 Device 012: ID ffff:1201
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

This is the result of a lsblk :

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop1         7:1    0 142,2M  1 loop /snap/chromium/2082
loop2         7:2    0 255,6M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36
loop3         7:3    0    47M  1 loop /snap/snapd/16292
loop4         7:4    0    48M  1 loop /snap/snapd/16778
loop5         7:5    0 346,3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/115
loop6         7:6    0  63,2M  1 loop /snap/core20/1623
loop7         7:7    0  45,9M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/592
loop8         7:8    0  55,6M  1 loop /snap/core18/2560
loop9         7:9    0  91,7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop10        7:10   0 400,8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/112
loop11        7:11   0  81,3M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1534
loop12        7:12   0   219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77
loop14        7:14   0    62M  1 loop /snap/core20/1611
loop15        7:15   0  54,2M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/558
loop16        7:16   0 142,2M  1 loop /snap/chromium/2076
loop17        7:17   0  55,6M  1 loop /snap/core18/2566
sda           8:0    0   2,7T  0 disk 
└─sda1        8:1    0   2,7T  0 part 
nvme0n1     259:0    0   477G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:2    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─nvme0n1p2 259:3    0 476,4G  0 part /
nvme1n1     259:1    0   477G  0 disk 
└─nvme1n1p1 259:4    0   477G  0 part
```

Does this mean that the Drive is dead and I shouldn't expect any recovery on the data that was stocked in it ? Or is there any way to make it happens ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the same problem because the scsi block module was not loaded. In `make menuconfig`, the SCSI block device driver can usually be found in the following location:

```
Device Drivers--->
    SCSI device support--->
        <*>SCSI disk support
```

The kernel version I am using is 6.4.0.

Comment: The asker is using Ubuntu. They have that support in their kernel or as module, 100% certain.